# The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data- Although I have cors

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-video

I try to display a video in canvas, but I got this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data
```

I though it because the video doesn't have a CORS, but when I test it using [test-cors](https://www.test-cors.org/#?client_method=GET&client_credentials=false&server_url=https%3A%2F%2Fres.cloudinary.com%2Fdwaquopnm%2Fvideo%2Fupload%2Fv1582007937%2Fblink2013_itacxp.mp4&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_tabs=remote), I can see that this video has CORS definition because I'm getting the response:

[image]

Url with cors:

https://res.cloudinary.com/dwaquopnm/video/upload/v1582007937/blink2013_itacxp.mp4

Url without cors:

http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_2160p_60fps_normal.mp4?fbclid=IwAR0KkYR0f8R0GkJ1UhpDMaVVbOhJ33DEpJ5UhHlz2qwH3ZvPdrS_WTrZMME

What can I do to solve this error? I can't use proxy becuase I have a cdn for the videos. (one server is in usa, the another is in china) so if I use proxy I missing the cdn point.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 var v = document.getElementById('my-video');
 var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var back = document.createElement('canvas');
 var backcontext = back.getContext('2d');
 
 var cw,ch;
  
  console.log({ v });
 
 v.addEventListener('play', function(){
  cw = v.clientWidth;
  ch = v.clientHeight;
  canvas.width = cw;
  canvas.height = ch;
  back.width = cw;
  back.height = ch;
  draw(v,context,backcontext,cw,ch);
 },false);
 
},false);

function draw(v,c,bc,w,h) {
  
 if(v.paused || v.ended) return false;
 // First, draw it into the backing canvas
 bc.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
 // Grab the pixel data from the backing canvas
 var idata = bc.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
 var data = idata.data;
 
 idata.data = data;
 // Draw the pixels onto the visible canvas
 c.putImageData(idata,0,0);
 // Start over!
 setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,bc,w,h);
}
```

```css
#c {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin: -180px 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    height="264"
    poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dwaquopnm/video/upload/v1582007937/blink2013_itacxp.mp4" type="video/mp4" crossorign="anonymous" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
        >supports HTML5 video</a
      >
    </p>
  </video>
  
  <canvas id="c" ></canvas> 


  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.6/video.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your video doesn't have its `crossorigin` attribute set. The request is made as "no-cors".